# How to change the Wordpress email icon?

Tags: email, favicon

When emails go out from a WordPress site, there is a site icon that goes with them and appears in email clients. This icon is taken from the WordPress favicon that is set under Appearance > Customize > Site Identity > Site Icon.

Here's a generic example if the icon I'm talking about (the orange circle):
[image]

On my site, I've replaced the icon with something different, but the emails coming from the site are still using the old icon. How can I get it to update?

UPDATE: I've realized that this has to go with the site template I'm using. Other emails from the site (contact forms, newsletter) don't have the icon. I'll have to figure this out with the template developer.

Comment: You referenced an image, but I don’t see any.

Comment: there are no images in your question, what tool are you using to send emails?